# Remove header from Primefaces Dialog

Tags: css, primefaces, dialog

Is there a way to remove the header from a dialog opened with the Primefaces Dialog Framework?
I know I can set a custom header (see code snipped), but how to remove it at all? I don't want to remove it from all dialog, so overriding the CSS class `.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar` is not an option.

```
 Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        options.put("modal", true);
        options.put("width", 640);
        options.put("height", 340);
        options.put("contentWidth", "100%");
        options.put("contentHeight", "100%");
        options.put("headerElement", "customheader");

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("viewCars", options, null);
```

Comment: You know you can add a css class and use that to remove it from just one dialog

Comment: Uhm, but how to add it? I have tried including a css rule directly in the xhtml-page overriding .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar and using display:none but it doesn't work. I have tried adding the css attribute in a javascript-ready function but it doens't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with help of jQuery's [Class Selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Add following java script inside page where you want to show dialog

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function removeDialogHeader(xhr, status, args){
                var showHeader=args.showDialogHeader;
                if (!showHeader){
                    //jquery gets all elements with class name ui-dialog-titlebar
                    var elements= $(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
                    //to remove elements
                    elements.remove();
                    //or you can achive the same effect by inserting display:none into element style
                    //elements.css("display", "none");
                }
            }
        </script>
```

modify managed bean method to make header visibility configurable

```
public void viewCars() {
    Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("resizable", false);
    //...
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("viewCars", options, null);
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("showDialogHeader", false);
}
```

and, assuming that you have p:commandButton to show dialog, call JS function after Ajax is completed

```
<p:commandButton value="Show dialog" actionListener="#{testBean.viewCars()}" oncomplete="removeDialogHeader(xhr, status, args);"/>
```

Comment: That's cool, thx. Note: I have to insert the javascript into the "base" page, the page where the button is located.

Comment: @Zardo And "base" page is "page where you want to show dialog" as I tried to describe with my "Tarzan words" :). Your description is much better then mine. Yes, it is page where your button is located.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case if anyone stumbles upon the same issue. You can simply override in your page:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: effectively this is not an answer to the question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `showHeader` attribute of `p:dialog`, like in the below example:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="exampleWidget" showHeader="false">
  <!-- your content -->
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "remove header"? It could be "do not show header"? If so, you can define a css class like:

```
.dialog-no-header.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    display: none;
}
```

and use it in the target dialog:

```
<p:dialog class="dialog-no-header" ...
```

Comment: no you can't, not with the dialog framework op is using

Comment: @Kukeltje you are right. I will check it today later on, thanks!